# WordPress 3 Multisite using subdomains.- DNS on Cpanel question

Tags: multisite

using google to search for answers to how to setup a cpanel"based" domain to use with WordPress 3 Multisite using subdomains (subdomain1.domain.com, subdomain2.domain.com etc.)

answer: "just go to subdomains in Cpanel, use * and point it to public_html"....

that works, but (and here's the question):

now the good old webmail.domainname.com, cpanel.domainname.com, whm.domainname.com etc. doesn't work anymore

So, question: how to do it 100% properly, so all normal functionality remains and still enable the subdomain possibility with WP Multisite ?

Comment: You have the most unfortunate random Gravatar ever.

Comment: I think he should flag it as a bug.

Comment: Brilliant LOL! Hacking the random Gravatar, must be a new trend

Answer (score 3):

When you're adding the wildcard subdomain, you need to make sure it is registered *last* in your ANAME records.  Then make sure all of the static subdomains (`webmail.domainname.com`, `cpanel.domainname.com`, etc) appear before it.

When using wildcard subdomains, the server starts at the top of the list and works its way down.  If all you have listed is your `*` subdomain, that will override the server's defaults (I'm assuming your static subdomains weren't explicitly set up before).  So you need to list the static ones first or you'll lose them.

Comment: I have listed the webmail, cpanel, whm. etc. as A -records . The * wildcard is listed last (seeing through WHM->edit DNS Zone)

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to install the domain mapping plugin: http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/

also, check that the CNAME record exists (ask hosting support)

Comment: I have listed the webmail, cpanel, whm. etc. as A -records . The * wildcard is listed last (seeing through WHM->edit DNS Zone)